# Parar parámetros de un formulario a un archivo html y ejecutar este

Tags: html5

Pasar datos de un formulario a parámetro de llamada de un archivo html y ejecutar.

Tengo definido esto en el formulario:

---

```
<FORM METHOD=...........................ACTION=.......>

       Ingresar su Número de Empleado:
       <INPUT TYPE = "text" SIZE = "9" MAXLENGTH = "9" NAME = "numemp"> <br>
       Ingresar los 3 Últimos Dígitos de su RUT: 
       <INPUT TYPE = "text" SIZE = "3" MAXLENGTH = "3" NAME = "pinrut" > <br>
       <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE = "Enviar">
       <INPUT TYPE="reset" VALUE = "Borrar">
</FORM>
```

---

Y al rellenar el formulario y presionar el botón "Submit" deseo que se invoque el archivo   `http://WWW.DESC.HTML#"&numemp""&pinrut"`  (quedando, por ejemplo así: `http://WWW.DESC.HTML#H60800032`)    y ejedutar dicho archivo con los parámetros pasados.

Agradecere ayuda para completar el código necesario.

Eduardo.

Answer (score 0):

Si usas PHP en el backend, tu formulario en **HTML** debe lucir de la siguiente manera:

```
<FORM METHOD="GET" ACTION="datos.php">

       Ingresar su Número de Empleado:
       <INPUT TYPE = "text" SIZE = "9" MAXLENGTH = "9" NAME = "numemp"> <br>
       Ingresar los 3 Últimos Dígitos de su RUT: 
       <INPUT TYPE = "text" SIZE = "3" MAXLENGTH = "3" NAME = "pinrut" > <br>
       <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE = "Enviar">
       <INPUT TYPE="reset" VALUE = "Borrar">
</FORM>
```

Y tu archivo **datos.php**

```
<html>
<body>

valor numemp <?php echo $_GET["numemp"]; ?><br>
valor pinrut: <?php echo $_GET["pinrut"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Recuerda que **php** puede ser embebido en archivos **.html** esa es la razón por la que en el archivo **datos.php** hay codigo **html**.
Aqui documentacion oficial:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp
http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php

Espero ayudarte. Suerte con lo que estes haciendo.